# Permuting the terms of a sequence does not affect its convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x_n$ be a sequence such that $x_n \rightarrow 0$.  Let $\sigma\colon\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$ be a bijection. Define a new sequence $y_n:= x_ {\sigma (n)} $. Show that $ y_n \rightarrow 0 $.

**ATTEMPT**
Since $x_n$ converges to 0 implies after a certain $n>n_{0}$ all its terms will lie between $(0-\epsilon,0+\epsilon$). As $\sigma$ is a bijection so it is increasing function. If I take set of subscripts of original sequence, I take all $n$ after $n>n_0$ such that set $\{ n_1 ,n_2,n_3,n_4,\ldots\}$ where all $n_{i} ,i=1,2,3,\ldots$ are bigger than $n_0$. So applying $\sigma$ function which is an increasing function I get new increasing sequence of subscripts. Now I need to claim that $x_i = \sigma (n_i)$ in order to make furthure progress. But how? Thanks

Comment: A bijection doesn't have to be necessarily increasing.

Comment: I took the liberty of giving the question a less symbol-heavy title

Comment: @TrevorWilson can you explain title

Comment: is it true that only bijections are of form sigma(n) = kn ,where k is even

Comment: A permutation is a bijection from a set to itself (such as $\sigma$.)  So the question asks: if we take a sequence that converges to zero, and we use a permutation to rearrange its terms, does it still converge to zero?  (And there is nothing special about zero here.)

Comment: No, that statement about bijections is not true.  In fact, *no* function of that form is a bijection.  (No odd numbers are in the range, so it cannot be a surjection.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Intuitively: The property that there exists $n_0$ such that $|x_n|<\epsilon$ for all $n>n_0$ can be reformulated as: The number of terms *outside* the interval $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ is *finite*. In this reformulation we see that the order of $\mathbb N$ doesn't matter.

Explicitly, one can proceed as follows: Given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $n_0$ such that $|x_n|<\epsilon$ for all $n>n_0$. Let $n_1=\max\{\sigma^{-1}(1),\ldots,\sigma^{-1}(n_0)\}$. Then for all $n>n_1$, $\sigma(n)$ is not in $\{1,\ldots,n_0\}$, hence $|y_n|=|x_{\sigma(n)}|<\epsilon$.

Comment: i couldnot understand about sigma inverses here

Comment: $\sigma$ is a bijection, so $\sigma^{-1}$ is the inverse permutation.